# How to create stored procedure with insert and update statements depends on condition?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure inserting data, and I need to update the stored procedure and check the order if exist before then update else if order not exist then insert the new value.

This is my stored procedure and what I need the idea to do but I got errors and I think there is mistakes in syntax :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_RESULT_COMMENT]
    @dept_id int,
    @order_id int,
    @comments varchar(1000),
    @comment_date datetime,
    @branch_id int,
    @testid int,
    @groupid int
AS
    SELECT comments 
    FROM Lab_Result_Comments 
    WHERE order_id = @order_id AND dept_id = @dept_id;

    IF comments IS NULL THEN 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments] ([dept_id], [order_id],[comments], [comment_date], branch_id, testid, groupid)
        VALUES (@dept_id, @order_id, @comments, @comment_date, @branch_id, @testid, @groupid)
    END;
    ELSE IF comments IS NOT NULL THEN 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments]
        SET [comments] = @comments
        WHERE order_id = @order_id
          AND dept_id = @dept_id
          AND Lab_Result_Comments.branch_id = @branch_id
 END;
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ADD_RESULT_COMMENT, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ADD_RESULT_COMMENT, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ADD_RESULT_COMMENT, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

How to solve procedure errors and fix it and execute it correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is a syntax error. If you peruse [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) you will see no `THEN` keyword is part of `IF`.

Comment: What is the primary key of this table?

Comment: Also note this whole pattern is unnecessary, see @AaronBertrand [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select something and then check for it - you need to store it into a variable:

```
DECLARE @DbComments VARCHAR(1000);  -- or whatever your column is defined as 

SELECT @DbComments = comments 
FROM Lab_Result_Comments 
WHERE order_id = @order_id AND dept_id = @dept_id;
```

You need to **ensure** that this `SELECT` can only return a **single** value - otherwise you'll get other errors....

Furthermore:

- There is no `THEN` - just drop those
- If you want to continue after the `IF` block - **do not** use a semicolon after `END`

Try this code:

```
IF @DbComments IS NULL    -- *NO* THEN here
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ......
END                       -- *NO* semicolon here
ELSE 
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments] .......
END;
```

The check in the `ELSE` clause is also not necessary - just leave it off.

**Update:** ok, the whole procedure would look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_RESULT_COMMENT]
    @dept_id int,
    @order_id int,
    @comments varchar(1000),
    @comment_date datetime,
    @branch_id int,
    @testid int,
    @groupid int
AS
    DECLARE @DbComments VARCHAR(1000);  -- or whatever your column is defined as 

    SELECT @DbComments = comments 
    FROM Lab_Result_Comments 
    WHERE order_id = @order_id AND dept_id = @dept_id;

    IF @DbComments IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments] ([dept_id], [order_id],[comments], [comment_date], branch_id, testid, groupid)
        VALUES (@dept_id, @order_id, @comments, @comment_date, @branch_id, @testid, @groupid)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments]
        SET [comments] = @comments
        WHERE order_id = @order_id
          AND dept_id = @dept_id
          AND Lab_Result_Comments.branch_id = @branch_id
    END;
```

But as @charlieface mentioned and posted a link to an Aaron Bertrand blog post - you could do this more easily like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_RESULT_COMMENT]
    @dept_id int,
    @order_id int,
    @comments varchar(1000),
    @comment_date datetime,
    @branch_id int,
    @testid int,
    @groupid int
AS
BEGIN
    -- just try to UPDATE the row
    UPDATE [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments]
    SET [comments] = @comments
    WHERE order_id = @order_id
      AND dept_id = @dept_id
      AND Lab_Result_Comments.branch_id = @branch_id

    -- check if update was unsuccessful --> row doesn't exist yet, so insert
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Lab_Result_Comments] ([dept_id], [order_id],[comments], [comment_date], branch_id, testid, groupid)
        VALUES (@dept_id, @order_id, @comments, @comment_date, @branch_id, @testid, @groupid)
    END;
END;
```

Comment: `IF EXISTS` probably more correct, but see Aaron Bertrand mentioned above

Comment: where i will declare the variable after as or before as because i have another variables used with stored procedure, can you post the complete procedure , thank you

Comment: @ZiadAdnan: whole procedure added in my response

Comment: @Charlieface: updated my response to include the approach Aaron would recommend